# Setting icon for TextInputLayout helper text and centering it to top

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

So I need to set up 2 things:

1. Icon for helper text in TextInputLayout
2. Center it to TOP, since helper text might be multiline

It might look something like this:

[image]

Is there easy of doing working around this, without making my own TextInputLayout?

Answer (score 0):

Solving this melts down to following 2 possible solutions:

**First is to change the `Rect` of the `Drawable` itself by setting the bounds (coordinates X and Y), drawback of this solution is whenever layout is redrawn (orientation change etc.), this has to be done again.**

```
        findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.textinput_helper_text)?.run {
            compoundDrawables.first()?.run {
                setBounds(
                    bounds.left,
                    bounds.top - this@with.height.div(2),
                    bounds.right,
                    bounds.bottom - this@with.height.div(2)
                )
                bottom = this@with.height.div(2)
            }
        }
```

**Second solution is to add new `ImageView` in front of the helper `TextView` and add `padding` to it, so it's pushed up.**
It's not a one liner, but it can be formed into easy to use method as such:

```
fun TextInputLayout.setStartHelperTextIcon(
    @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int,
    paddingPx: Int
) {
    with(findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.textinput_helper_text)) {
        (this?.parent?.parent as? LinearLayout)?.run {
            if(findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.text_input_layout_helper_icon) == null) {
                addView(
                    ImageView(context).apply {
                        id = R.id.text_input_layout_helper_icon

                        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        )
                        setPadding(
                            paddingPx,
                            0,
                            paddingPx,
                            paddingPx + this@with.height.div(2)
                        )
                    },
                    0
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was pretty surprised that Android hasn't provided such a way to setup an icon of helper text, which sounds like a common need in some projects. This solution looks so hacky...

Comment: what happened to drawableRes ?